# Distributing Clang and LLVM on Windows easily

Tags: c, visual-studio, clang, llvm

I have software I am developing that uses Clang and LLVM as its backend on 64 bit Windows systems. However, I am realizing that LLVM uses Visual Studio as its backend. I really want to avoid requiring everyone who uses my software to install Visual Studio Express, as I am aiming to make installation of my software no hassle, ideally with all requirements contained in a single installer file. However I am having a lot of trouble getting around requirements for link.exe, kernel32.lib, and libcmt.lib without installing Visual Studio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

LLVM does not use Visual Studio "as its backend", surely.

Besides the compiler itself you're certainly in need of various components like linker and the standard libraries. LLVM / clang does not provide anything like this (or, may feel brave and try lld instead of link.exe), thus you have 2 options so far:

1. Distribute / force the users to get missing pieces from Visual Studio (I'm not a lawyer, but as far as I understand, you cannot distribute the libs due to EULA. I'd suggest you to better study this area or perhaps contact a lawyer).
2. Use the stuff from MingW

Comment: I guess backend might not be the right wording, I meant more as a requirement to convert C code into an exe. I'm being very careful with legality so I'm not even going to try distributing the libs, I looked around and didn't find any way Microsoft provided except through downloading Visual Studio, which seems rather messy. I've looked at MingW too and I think it's the better option but still not one I'm thrilled with. I may have found a third possibility though, a compiler called TCC, the Tiny C Compiler. So far it appears to work well and be very easy to install. Thanks for your input!